# Ansible /etc/ansible missing PIP

Tags: ansible

I have recently reimaged my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and after installing Ansible(2.7.5) via PIP (python2) I have realised that `/etc/ansible` is missing.

Removing the package and reinstalling it has not changed anything. Apart from missing the `/etc/ansible` Ansible is working. Any idea how to force the creation of directory on the install?
Or shall I just create it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can create is manually. Or, you might want to take the one from the Ubuntu package (when there is a reason not to install it completely).

```
# dpkg -l | grep ansible
ii  ansible                                2.7.5-1ppa~bionic                      all

# apt-file list ansible | grep ansible.cfg
ansible: /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
```